# Confusion about the physical meaning of conditional convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

So I have a question about the convergence of a series here:

It says:

> Find the radius and interval of convergence, then identify the values of $x$ for which the series converges absolutely and conditionally:
>
> $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^3(n)}{n+1}(2x+1)^n$

I already found the radius of convergence. It's $\frac{1}{2}$. The interval of convergence is $[-1,0)$.

I'm confused about the 2nd part though. Does it converge absolutely on the interval $(-1,0)$ and conditionally converge at $x=-1$? I am asking because I don't understand what does conditional converge physically mean.

Comment: No I get the definition but is there a physical way of interpreting what conditional means? I saw something about rearranging terms in a series.

Comment: Got it, wasn't sure what you meant by "physically." You're right: it does conditionally converge at $x = -1$ because the series for $\vert a_n\vert$ diverges. Also, yes, conditionally convergent series can be re-arranged to give any value or even diverge.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot :) .